# FAKE, TeamCity and old versions of NuGet packages

Tags: f#, teamcity, nuget-package, f#-fake

I use FAKE to build my projects and produce NuGet packages. 
Let's say I have a project "MyProjectA". Then TeamCity, using the FAKE script, creates a NuGet package containing MyProjectA:

```
MyProjectA-1.0.1.nupkg
```

Then I want to use this package in another project: "MyProjectB". So in FAKE I add the dependency:

```
NuGet (fun p -> 
        { p with               
            Authors = authors
            Project = "MyProjectB"
            // ...
            Dependencies = ["MyProjectA",  GetPackageVersion "./packages/" "MyProjectA" |> RequireExactly ]
            Files = // ..
         }
```

Improtant: TeamCity produces a NuGet for MyProjectB as well (let's say I need it in yet another project).

At some point I realize I need to apply a fix to MyProjectA. So I do it and TeamCity/FAKE produces a newer version of the NuGet package:

```
MyProjectA-1.0.2.nupkg
```

Then I update MyProjectB as well (i.e. make sure it refers to the new version of MyProjectA).

HOWEVER: TeamCity produces a MyProjectB NuGet package that refers to the old version of MyProjectA!!

I looked into TeamCity build folder and noticed there's a "packages" folder containing:

```
+-+ packages
  | MyProjectA-1.0.1.nupkg
  | MyProjectA-1.0.2.nupkg
```

Looks like TC doesn't clean its working folders, which is fine as it reduces the time needed to build a project. In this case however it also causes FAKE GetPackageVersion function to fail (I guess it takes the first package the matches the name - in that case the old package is always the first one in alphabetical order, as it has a lower version number).

For now the only fix I found is to manually delete the old package from a TC folder. Is there a better solution ?

Comment: I have hit the same issue. I copied GetPackageVersion and changed it to sort and use the latest instead of the first. Another alternative is to read the output of `nuget.exe list -source <packages dir> <package name>` which has the advantage of using Nuget metadata instead of string splits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete the build dir before build in TeamCity. In your VCS Root, assuming you use git there's a setting called `Clean Files Policy` set that to `All untracked files`. And it will delete all the packages before every build. Again assuming you don't have them in source control.

Comment: Interesting - I'll give it a try. Thanks!